# Plot multiple lists with different size side by side?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot

I have 4 lists as follows:

```
x_name=[’01-2014’,’03-2014’,’05-2014’,’01-2015’,’03-2015’]
x_value=[3,5,1,5,7]

z_name==[’01-2014’,’03-2014’,’04-2014’,’07-2014’,’05-2014’,’01-   
        2015’,’02-2015’,’03-2015’]
z_value=[6,8,2,4,6,8,1,2]
```

I want to plot these lists side by side, so that if they have identical names in (`x_name` and `z_name`), their corresponding values (in `x_value` and `z_value`) should be plotted side by side, and the name in `z_name` which are not in `x_name` (e.g., ’04-2014’, ’02-2015’,etc), should be assign to 0 in the plot. I have coded the following:

```
bar_width = 0.75
opacity = 0.8
index = len(z_name)

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
rects0=axs.bar(z_name,  
       z_value,bar_width,alpha=opacity,color='red',label=key)

rects0=axs.bar(index + bar_width, x_value,  
       bar_width,alpha=opacity,color='g',label='true')

plt.xlabel(‘x and z names’)
plt.ylabel('x and z values')
```

But, something is wrong and I can not assign the 0 value to those which are not in `x_name`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- Use the correct x-values for both the bar charts
- Use `align=edge` mode and positive and negative bar width's to place the bar adjacent to each other
- Use a smaller bar width to avoid the overlap of the bars

I do not know why you were using `index = len(z_name)`

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_name=['01-2014','03-2014','05-2014','01-2015','03-2015']
x_value=[3,5,1,5,7]

z_name=['01-2014','03-2014','04-2014','07-2014','05-2014','01-2015','02-2015','03-2015']
z_value=[6,8,2,4,6,8,1,2]

bar_width = 0.25
opacity = 0.8
index = len(z_name)

fig, axs = plt.subplots()

rects0=axs.bar(z_name, z_value, bar_width, align='edge', alpha=opacity, color='r')
rects0=axs.bar(x_name, x_value, -bar_width, align='edge',alpha=opacity, color='g')

plt.xlabel('x and z names')
plt.ylabel('x and z values')
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
```

[image]